# How can I add white space before an element's content using CSS?

Tags: css, unicode, space, css-content

None of the following code works:

```
p:before { content: " "; }
p:before { content: "&nbsp;"; }
```

How do I add white space before an element's content?

Note: I need to color the *border-left* and the *margin-left* for semantic use and use the space as a colorless margin. :)

Comment: Why not just add simple margin.

Comment: Maybe because margin / padding affects whole block. text-indent would be a better choice

Comment: I need to color the border-left and the margin-left for semantic use :) I may add several `element:before { content:"[a kind of space]"; background: mycolor;}` as well. All ways I wanted to know a way to add spaces, kinda fun!

Comment: @Hugolpz: You could do basically the same thing with `p:first-letter { border-left: 1ex solid mycolor; }`.

Comment: @carn margins are static, space width is relative to font size

Answer (score 315, accepted):

You can use the Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) of a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space):

```
p:before { content: "\00a0 "; }
```

See **[JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uMFHH/3/)** (style improved [by Jason Sperske](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552397/css-how-to-add-white-space-before-elements-content#comment23778158_16552398)).

Comment: I made a slight edit so you can see it's effect: http://jsfiddle.net/uMFHH/3/ (otherwise it just looks like a margin, which brings up a good question, why not just add a margin?)

Comment: Because I need to color the border-left and the margin-left :)

Comment: Why the space at the end of `"\00a0 "`? Is that necessary or can we just do `"\00a0"`?

Comment: @jbyrd: not neccessary (see http://jsfiddle.net/nhyw6e9q/ ). I left it there to show that normal space are not accounted for.

Answer (score 48):

Don't fart around with inserting spaces.  For one, older versions of [IE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer) won't know what you're talking about.  Besides that, though, there are cleaner ways in general.

For colorless indents, use the [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) property.

```
p { text-indent: 1em; }
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ng7W/)

If you want the space to be colored, you might consider adding a thick left border to the first letter.  (I'd almost-but-not-quite say "instead", because the indent can be an issue if you use both.  But it feels dirty to me to rely solely on the border to indent.)  You can specify how far away, and how wide, the color is using the first letter's left margin/padding/border width.

```
p:first-letter { border-left: 1em solid red; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ng7W/5/)

Comment: If you're stuck supporting IE<8, this method will work while before/after pseudo elements will not.

Comment: @cimmanon: Yep.  According to MDN, this works even in IE 3 (though i didn't even realize they *had* CSS back then :P).

Comment: You cannot color an indentation such `{ text-indent: 1em; }`. But we can color a space such `:before {content: "\00a0 "; background: #000; }`. [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hugolpz/3ng7W/1/)

Comment: @Hugolpz: A text-indent?  Nope. can't color that differently, AFAIK.   But [a border?  Sure.](http://jsfiddle.net/3ng7W/2/)  :)

Comment: Oh, we cannot add several content, [see Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ng7W/4/). Too bad...

Comment: Yeah...`:before` basically picks the imaginary element that precedes a real element.  If you say `p:before` twice, you select that same pseudo-element both times.

Comment: This `:first-letter {border-left: }` is witty! +1

Comment: I was going to say that in my situation I can not use the padding, but I thought about it a little and then figured out how to do it, such a better solution, for MY situation anyway.

Answer (score 13):

```
/* Most accurate setting if you only want
   to do this with a CSS pseudo element */
p:before { 
    content: "\00a0";
    padding-right: 5px; /* If you need more space between contents */
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Since you are looking for adding space between elements, you may need something as simple as a *margin-left* or *padding-left*.  Here are examples of both (http://jsfiddle.net/BGHqn/3/):

This will add 10 pixels to the left of the paragraph element

```
p {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

or if you just want some padding within your paragraph element

```
p {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```